# (1/1) RuntimeException The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-5.6

i am trying to host a laravel 5.6 app on heroku and after pushing all the files on line and running the app i get the error

> (1/1) RuntimeException
>   The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.

i have tried placing the `AES-128-CBC` on `config/app.php` file then uploading and then rining `artisan key:generate` then `artisan config:cache` but am still getting the same same error.
My database is hosted on db4free.net.

Comment: Have you tried this solution?
https://github.com/phanan/koel/issues/516#issuecomment-271292633

Comment: What's `strlen(config('app.key'))` return?

Comment: I found where the mistake was, i had changed the app_key but had not added  base64: before app key on the config vars on heroku like base64:qwertyuiuytrew= . Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Run PHP artisan `key:generate` in your command. It automatically appends base64 to your constant values.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `base64:2egG+` to the string in the environment file worked for me